# Updating Evernote notes with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, evernote

I'm trying to update a note in Evernote.
I set a filter, get notes list and I can also change the note's title.
But when I try to change note content, nothing happens.

```
from evernote.api.client import EvernoteClient
import evernote.edam.type.ttypes as Types
from evernote.edam.notestore.ttypes import NoteFilter, NotesMetadataResultSpec
client = EvernoteClient(token="xxxxx", sandbox=True)
note_store = client.get_note_store()
updated_filter = NoteFilter(words='abaco')
result_list = note_store.findNotesMetadata(updated_filter, 0, 10000, NotesMetadataResultSpec(includeTitle=True))
for note in result_list.notes:
    print "----- TITLE -----\n%s\n----- GUID -----\n%s\n----- CONTENT -----\n%s" % (note.title, note.guid, note_store.getNoteContent(note.guid))
    note.title = "pippo"
    note.guid = note.guid
    note.content = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM "http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd">'
    note.content += '<en-note>Note updated</en-note>'
    note = note_store.updateNote(note)
```

I receive no error but the note is not updated.

I'm using Python 2.7.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The return value of [NoteStore#findNotesMetadata](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_findNotesMetadata) is [NotesMetadataList](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Struct_NotesMetadataList) that contains [NoteMetadata](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Struct_NoteMetadata), not [Note](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/Types.html#Struct_Note) object. In order to update notes, you should call [NoteStore#getNote](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getNote) first, update the field and call [NoteStore#updateNote](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_updateNote).